# Xpath creation issue

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium WebDriver with eclipse (2019-06) to do some testCases. I'm using xpath with my webDriver who's working correctly. But I try to get some informations in my DOM but I can't find the correct xpath to catch what I want.

I'm creating some Assert to compare the value find with the xpath in my page and the information I get in an excel file.
My code is structure in a html table and the info that I need to catch is in the same row than other info, and I don't know how to only catch one.

The simplify structure of my table is :

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="fp1 gray">
    <label>Portfolio</label>
  </td>
  <td class="data">
   <b class="xh-highlight">numPortfolio</b>
  </td>

  <td class="fp1 gray">
   <label>Instrument</label>
  </td>
  <td class="data">
   <b class="xh-highlight">numInstrument</b>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The xpath that I'm using to get the value "numPortfolio" of the portfolio is :

```
//tr[td[@class='fp1 gray']='Portfolio']/td[@class='data']/b[1]
```

I'm searching the value of the 'b' where the class is equals to 'data' and the 'td' before contains 'Portfolio' where the class is equals to 'fp1 gray'.

For the value of instrument "numInstrument" :

```
//tr[td[@class='fp1 gray']='Instrument']/td[@class='data']/b[1]
```

But this kind of xpath return me all the time the "numPortfolio" and the "labelInstrument" and I don't know how to specify that I only want the value of the 'b' just after and not each 'b' in 'tr'.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//td[@class='fp1 gray' and label[normalize-space(.)='Portfolio']]/following-sibling::td[1]/b

//td[@class='fp1 gray' and label[normalize-space(.)='Instrument']]/following-sibling::td[1]/b
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @supputuri
Do you have some extension who offers you an xpath ? Are you using Google Chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the extension who offers an xpath you can use an extension for Google Chrome called **XPath Helper** found [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl).

You could also (if you are using Google Chrome) **inspect** the web page by right clicking the page, then choose Inspect. When you are inspecting a page, you can right click any element in the inspector and choose Copy -> Copy XPath.

However, this may not always provide the best xpath. In this case, the inspector is providing the path `/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/b`, while it is probably better to go with the **`//td[@class='fp1 gray' and label[contains(text(),'Portfolio')]]/following-sibling::td[1]/b`** path since it has the correct class name and text attribute in it.

Comment: Thanks @supersoffi for your answer. I'm already using extensions that you advise me!